# Django WSGI application in a subdirectory?

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, wsgi

Recently, I wanted to put one of my WSGI applications into a subdirectory, so that the other directories that cointain various scripts would work as before. In order to do that, I added the following directive to my `httpd.conf` in global namespace (also tried to put it in the `VirtualHost`, which gave the same effects):

```
WSGIScriptAlias /hello/ /var/www/hello/hello.wsgi
```

Then, I ran `django-admin startproject hello`. After reloading Apache configs, I can confirm that `http://localhost/hello/` points to a Django "welcome" screen. Then, I edited `hello/urls.py` to add the following line in the `urlpatterns` tuple:

```
url(r'^hello/', 'hello.views.home'),
```

Next, I created hello/views.py with the following contents:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")
```

Unfortunately, when I try to visit `http://localhost/hello/hello`, I get a standard Apache 404 message and the following entry in the error log:

```
[Mon Dec 23 19:49:44 2013] [error] [client 31.182.131.38] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/hello/hello.wsgihello
```

Note the `hello.wsgihello`. The second `hello` is the text that appears after `/hello/` in the URL. For `http://localhost/hello/unknown`, it would be `hello.wsgiunknown`. Here's my `hello.wsgi`:

```
import os
import sys

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'hello.settings'

path = '/var/www/hello'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Did I do something wrong? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The file syntax in `/var/www/hello/hello.wsgi` confused me. Apparently, if one points to `/var/www/hello/hello.wsgi/` instead, the configuration works fine.